# Creating a wrapping animation

Tags: animation

I am animating a plane which has to wrap around a cylinder. How can I approch this animation? The idea is the plane to be tape, which you put one end first then wrap the other around a cylinder.

[image]

I tried doing a shape key, however I cannot manage to make it good. I am thinking of doing armature, however I will do the vertex painting and bones.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the same result, so duplicate.